# WCF - The socket connection was aborted

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, networking

I m getting the following Exception, when i run WCF service on a remote host with TCP binding. basichttpbinding works however.

Also, when i host it in the same machine, it works as well.

Also using test client and connection to remote machine, TCP works as well.

Why do you think i m getting the following exception? what s the fix?

```
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.GetSectionEntity(String id)
   at Service1Client.GetSectionEntity(String id) in C:\src\Service1.cs:line 2318
   at GetSectionSync(Id sectionId, Boolean loadFromDbIfNotInCache) 
2011-02-22 10:41:13,888|WARN | HttpHandler|The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:29.9870000'.
2011-02-22 10:41:13,891|ERROR|HttpHandler|The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:29.9870000'.
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:29.9870000'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but if your service is working on your local machine and on a different binding then maybe the remote machine is already using the port? I believe the default is 888.

Comment: i can access to remote machine via the WCF test client and it works. and this works. http://remote:8080/service1, i can browse to this address. but i cant consume it...

Comment: @DarthVader - did you ever determine what the root cause was?

Comment: @RQDQ configuration that was.

Comment: @DarthVader, what did you change in the configuration to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, turn on WCF diagnostics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the points and all, but I would like to know what the root cause was as well.  This was the best advice I was able to give with the available information at the time.